# How to configure BulkInsert to insert as many records as it can and behave fuzzy?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using [EF Core Bulk Extensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) library. And this is the code that I use to insert a list of entities:

```
var entities = new List<Enttiy>();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
  var entity = new Entity();
  // setting properties
  entities.Add(entity);
}
using context = new DatabaseCotnext();
context.BulkInsert(entities);
```

The problem is that even if one record can not be inserted, it does not insert anything at all.

I don't want it to act transactionally and atomically. I want it to insert as many records as it can. For example, 900 out of 1000.

Is that possible?

**Update**:

In MariaDB and C#, this code works in a fuzzy manner:

```
public List<string> BulkInsert(List<T> entities)
{
    var problems = new List<string>();
    var table = entities.ToTable();
    var connectionString = ConnectionString;
    if (!connectionString.Contains("AllowLoadLocalInfile"))
    {
        connectionString = $"{connectionString};AllowLoadLocalInfile=true;";
    }
    using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.InfoMessage += (s, e) =>
    {
        foreach (var item in e.Errors)
        {
            problems.Add(item.Message);
        }
    };
    connection.Open();
    var bulkCopy = new MySqlBulkCopy(connection);
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TableName;
    try
    {
        var result = bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
        return problems;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Logger.LogException(ex);
        Logger.LogError(problems.Merge());
        throw new ServerException(ex.Message + ". See the logs for the list of problems. Also make sure your database schema, specially column orders is correct. And make sure that you use FakerHelper for correct formatting.");
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Looks like you are solving one problem by introducing another.  You are trying Upsert?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, MariaDB does it. So it's not introducing another problem.

Comment: Please post link about it. How is supported by MariaDb?